# Parallel Execution of a .net application

Tags: c#, executable

I want to write a small console application (C# 4.0/4.5) that will serve as a logger to a remote database.  Said application could be called from numerous peripheral automation components/programs, not of all which will be .NET based. (calls would be made via commandline: e.g., logme.exe appID, taskID, statusID, msg)

Question: what would happen if two or more of these programs were to execute the logger either a) at the same time, or b) while it's already in use elsewhere?

I'm unsure of the execution fundamentals and whether I should be concerned with this or not.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing bad would happen, your process would just run multiple times as if you double clicked it multiple times. As long as you're not trying to write to the same file multiple time or something similar you should be fine (in the case of writing to a remote database it should be handled for you).

If you want a more certain answer you'll have to post your console application code here so that we can tell you if nothing raises a red flag.

Comment: Thanks, that's all the confirmation I was looking for.  Nothing crazy going on by any means (one SQL Azure insert and some error handling), so if the general rule is that there's no conflict, I'll go with that and keep a wary eye out as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that a shared components can be handled in a multiprocessor environment. If that means using a `mutex` to lock a shared resource across multiple instances then that needs to be done.

See [Basic Synchronization](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx) by Joe Albahari on implementing differing locking operations.